# Android popup like IOS

Tags: android, view, popup

I need to implement popup dialog like in iOS, and show above some view (map point in this case), but don't know how to implement it. A screenshot is attached. Will be glad to read any proposals.

[image]

Comment: Search `CustomInfoWindow` in `Android`

Comment: Visit this,may be it can help you https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/

Comment: This can be put on hold as "Needs More Focus".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are adding it inside a mapview as from above image:

use this and change the features according to your requirement

```
static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(MELBOURNE)
                          .title("Melbourne")
                          .snippet("Population: 4,137,400"));
```

Refer this link: [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows)

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://capdroid.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/android-quick-action-menu/) example

Just call this when you want to open that dialog

```
 MyCustomDialog dialog = new MyCustomDialog(buttonView);
 dialog.show();
```

Comment: Oh, I will implement it in my another case) Your answer is very useful too. Thank you.